# Scrape YouTube Videos with Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to Scrape all Videos from 'TVFilthyFrank' for a friend. I have all links to every video of him.
I want to measure the size in MB for all videos now and download them.
I know I can just say `driver.get(VIDEO_URL)` and then just get the src out of the player but that would take very long and wouldt look nice. 
Is there anyway to get the video src (or at least some information to the vid) out of the video link ?

Comment: as I understood, you want to download video by giving youtube URL, right?

Comment: no, for example i want to search about this sentence 'best programing language 2020 ' after search i ant first two links of search results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try `youtube-dl`: https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl. It can be used in python code as modude and in shell.

To download all videos from channel TVFilthyFrank you can use `youtube-dl -f bestvideo+bestaudio --write-info-json https://www.youtube.com/user/TVFilthyFrank` (`-f bestvideo+bestaudio` means the best quality). `--write-info-json` means save metadata to json file.

Comment: but I don't want to get video links from Channel, I want them from search results

Comment: @EslamTantawy `youtube-dl "ytsearch:your search keywords"`, add ` --skip-download --write-info-json` if you want only metadata, without downloading videos.