# Scraping comments from youtube using python

Tags: screen-scraping

I wrote a code which loads a comments from a given url address of a youtube page, but I must add attributes to each comment and structure the comment and the attribute as a dataframe.
My question is which part of the html file must I embed in order to add  some new attribute?

Comment: why don't you just use the youtube api?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scrape YouTube Videos with Python and Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62129727/scrape-youtube-videos-with-python-and-selenium)